# Error installing homebrew - Tapping homebrew/core

Tags: homebrew

im a new mac os user and i'm trying to install homebrew in terminal.
things went pretty well until i face this error

==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1184486, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (61/61), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream
error: 1227 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

anyone face the same error?
and what should i do to install it successfully?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, after trying a bit I just removed the homebrew folder and re-installed homebrew by pasting the command in the terminal.

You can find the folder in /Opt/Homebrew

Once done with removing the folder paste this command in the terminal (the same command that you must have used to install it earlier)

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

[Navigate to the homebrew folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410825/apple-silicon-port-all-homebrew-packages-under-usr-local-opt-to-opt-homebrew#:~:text=Homebrew%20packages%20are%20currently%20installed,homebrew%20for%20Apple%20Silicon%20Macs.)